# Dependencies of libraries deployed in a Yocto bin_package

Tags: dependencies, libraries, yocto

I have a strange issue with library dependencies using Yocto. I'm building Yocto on two different build machines, M_a and M_b with exactly the same version of Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS).

A libs.tar.bz2 tarball deploys some libraries in my rootfs using the "inherit bin_package". The recipe is as simple as this:

```
$ cat recipe_0.1.bb
inherit bin_package
S = "${WORKDIR}/prebuilt"
SRC_URI = "file://libs.tar.bz2"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
```

Libraries included into the tarball are properly deployed on the final rootfs when building on M_a machine.

However, when building on M_b machine, I get a error:

```
ERROR: recipe-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libcustom.so contained in package recipe requires libglib-2.0.so.0()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_recipe? [file-rdeps]
```

My question is, does some of you know how Yocto extracts the list of dependencies of every single library included in the tarball? I would like to execute that command on M_a and M_b to compare the outputs and discover what's missing... Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: just my 2 cents: I would run 'bitbake -e recipe > log' for both machines and diff them

Comment: Thanks a lot, that could help. I will check that...

Answer (score 0):

You can admire the beautiful monstrosity in [meta/classes/package.bbclass::package_do_shlibs()](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/package.bbclass#n1738) -- but I'd start debugging by running a slightly simpler oneliner on the libraries and binaries in the two tarballs:

```
objdump -p libcustom.so | grep NEEDED
```

Comment: The tarball is the same in both compilations (the same repository is used for downloading sources in both build machines). So obviously the list of NEEDED libraries is exactly the same (I already checked that). As far as I know, yocto should not depend on any host library. This is a little bit crazy.

Comment: The referenced bbclass could be helpful. I will check for this ${HOST_PREFIX}objdump cross-tool command, as maybe it doesn't work exactly equal in both platforms. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the output of objdump -p libcustom.so | grep NEED, and the outputs are exactly the same set of libraries both in M_a and M_b machines.

However I found the "recipe.spec" file generated in the workdir contained different sets of libraries (libusb:386 and libsystemd:386 appear in one machine and not in the other one). That sounds really very strange to me, as I undestand Yocto is not a tool that depends on the host machine where the compilation is performed.

M_a and M_b have different sets of packages installed, but both of them have the minimum set of libraries needed to build Yocto. But there are more that 100 different packages and discover the package that breaks de compilations is quite difficult as each compilation takes a long time.